# Excluding some form element from jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

i am using a form with several textbox elements which i want to validate and few which i dont want to, i am using jquery .not() for this but i am not getting the desired result am i making some ayntax error or something here is my code

```
function validateRegisterClick(){
    var isValid = true;
    // Validate User Information.
    $('input[type=text], input[type=password]').not(':input[id$=txtMob], :input[id$=txtOfficeNo]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
                $(this).next()
                       .fadeIn('slow')
                       .removeClass()
                       .addClass('failure')
                       .fadeIn('slow')
                       .text("Can't be blank.");
                isValid = false;
            }
});
}
```

it also includes the txtMob and txtOfficeNo as i am using external javascript file so i am using this syntax 
--thanks
Mac

Comment: Seeing the form and then understanding the end goal would be useful. In the meantime, the selector seems to be formatted correctly for the following purpose: "Select all inputs of type text or type password, unless their IDs have the text 'txtMob' or 'txtOfficeNo' in them". If that's what the selector is meant to do (simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hueaM/), it's fine, and the problem lies elsewhere in the code.

Comment: i have debugged my script and checked the id for the case in which it is returning 'isValid=false' and the id what i got is 'ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMob' and 'ContentPlaceHolder1_txtOfficeNo'

Comment: That fits in with exactly how I interpreted your selector. Where is the problem? Side note: you are reinventing a wheel that doesn't need reinventing. jQuery's official validation plugin works great and has any easy API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the line in my above code solves the problem:

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=password]').not(':input[type=text][id$=txtMob], :input[type=text][id$=txtOfficeNo]').each(function ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the ids with -

```
$('input').not('input[id$=txtMob], input[id$=txtOfficeNo]').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: That's not excluding a substring match, which I believe is what he intends to do.

Comment: i am using external js file and the page also contains a master page i am sorry i didn't mention that so in this case i think #txtMob and #txtOfficeno will not work

Comment: I'm not understanding what 'external js' and 'master page' have to do with this. The fact that a JS or an 'include' are part of your equation should be irrelevant.

Comment: @Greg actually while using master pages in asp.net it add some extra elements to every element id so if we access that element with same id as we define it will generate error so if we are using internal javascript file that is inside our page in head section we have to use something like <%=buttonXXX.ClientID%> while in external javascript file it will not work so we have to use something like '$("input[id$='txtBoxPasswrd']")'

Comment: So, as per my first comment, then. ;-) It's not the fact that JS is external or the fact that you have a Master page, though. That's coincidental; the problem is simply that you need substring match for automatically-generated IDs.